# Ignore media folders for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a website that uses a JS generator that matches letters from a few thousand images. Now the site is insanely slow for some reason, and I think that it is because wordpress is indexing the 12+ folders that each have ~700 images. Is there a way to tell it to ignore those images?

https://makeambigrams.com/ambigram-generator/

Comment: post your generator code, this is too arbitrary of a question

Comment: No I just don't want the images to appear in the media folder of wordpress, as I think it is slowing everything down.